Обновить одну из дублирующихся строк Postgres
Есть таблица с полными дублями данных, допустим:
Create table Tbl  (val1 int, val2 int, val3 date);  
select * 
from (values  
     (1, 2, now()), (1, 2, now()), (1, 2, now()) ) 
     t(t1, t2, t3);

Дублей может быть сколь угодно много. Мне нужно сделать строки уникальными (конкретно, хочу добавить каждой дате по 1 секунде относительно предыдущей).
В ms sql я бы мог написать CTE с row_number'ом и updat'нуть само CTE - Постгрес такого не позволяет.
Есть ли возможность осуществить задуманное, не генеря доп столбец (с помощью которого можно будет различать записи)?

это обновит все строки таблицы, мне же нужно сделать это только  в рамках дублей, притом так, чтобы все они обновились на разные (различающиеся единицей) значения

Если строки в таблице ничем не отличаются,
можно сделать различение записей через использование SEQUENCE, который последовательно генерирует различные значения.
Посмотрите пример.
Create table Tbl  (val1 int, val2 int, val3 timestamp);  
insert into tbl
select * 
from (values  
     (1, 2, now()), (1, 2, now()), (1, 2, now()) ) 
     t(t1, t2, t3);
select * from tbl;




val1
val2
val3




1
2
2024-04-11 12:46:30.152795


1
2
2024-04-11 12:46:30.152795


1
2
2024-04-11 12:46:30.152795



create temporary sequence tsec start 1 increment 1;
update tbl
  set val3=val3+nextval('tsec')* interval '1 sec';
select * from tbl;




val1
val2
val3




1
2
2024-04-11 12:46:31.152795


1
2
2024-04-11 12:46:32.152795


1
2
2024-04-11 12:46:33.152795




Очень интересное решение, спасибо!
